# Cómo obtener la URL de la última redirección al solicitar una página desde PHP

Tags: php, redirección, cabeceras-http

Si tenemos esta URL: `https://WebSite_Redirecciona.com/aaabbb`

Que lo que hace es un **Redirect** hacia otra página, en este ejemplo va directamente a la website `http://www.google.com/`.

¿Cómo puedo en PHP obtener la URL a la que se está redireccionando (es decir, `'http://www.google.com/'`)? Me interesa obtener la dirección del último redireccionamiento que se haga al solicitar la primera URL.

---

Estoy todo el rato probando con `$ch = curl_init($url);` pero me devuelve el acortador y no la dirección última que deseo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede realizar por medio de la función [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-headers.php)  para obtener las cabeceras de la respuesta para luego buscar el indice `Location` que tendrá la `URL` real o final de la redirección.

```
$link = 'linkAcordatoGoogle';
//Obtenemos los Headers
$headers = get_headers($link,1); 
//accedemos al indice Location
$url = $headers['Location'];
//Si es Array , Iteramos y obtenemos todas las url
if (is_array($url)) {
  foreach ($url as $url) {
    echo $url . "\n";
  }  
} else {
  // si no , simplemente imprimimos la url
  echo $url;
}
```

Comment: ¿Hay algún caso en el que `$headers['Location']` sea un array?

Comment: @Mariano claro, intente con `http://fat.ly/redirectdemo`

Comment: Ya entendí. Cuando hay redirecciones en cadena (pagA -> pagB -> pagC), va sumando cada encabezado de cada página y los devuelve en array. Gracias, no lo sabía.

Answer (score 1):

El código de Dev. Joel no funciona porque Location debe estar en minúscula (location).
He hecho una función para poder reusar el código.
No la he probado para el caso de que haya más de una redirección.

```
/**
 * Si la URL que le pasamos como parámetro tiene redirecciones, se devuelve la URL de la última redirección
 * Si no hay redirecciones, devolvemos la misma URL
 * Si la URL no funciona devuelve FALSE
 * return string
 */
function get_ultima_redireccion($url){
    $headers = get_headers($url,1);
    // Si la URL no funciona devuelve FALSE
    if (! $headers) return false;

    // Si no hay redirecciones, devolvemos la misma URL
    if (! $all_url = $headers['location']) return $url;

    //Si es Array , Iteramos y obtenemos todas las url
    if (is_array($all_url)) {
    foreach ($all_url as $url) {
        $ultima_url = $url;
    }  
    return $ultima_url;
    } 
    return $all_url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> No respondo a la pregunta, esto es para obtener la **página** usando cURL, **no la URL**.
>   Ver [la respuesta de Dev.Joel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/134583/127)

Para hacer que CURL siga la redirección automáticamente de forma transparente para tu script, con [**curl_setopt()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php) se configura `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```